# Problem with different extension files upload at streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file-upload, streamlit

I'm trying to let the user select what files he wants to upload, but I'm facing a problem.

For example, there are two types of extension files the user can upload (`csv` and `xlsx`). After he upload his file `streamlit` needs to open the file and shows as a dataframe. But in code I did, I create two if's to read the files with `xlsx` extension and csv extension, but didn't worked as expected...

Upload file Button:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import streamlit as st

if option =='Cg':
    st.header("Cálculo do índice de Capabilidade Cg")
    st.text("Irei adicionar algum texto aqui posteriormente para explicar o índice de capabilidade Cdl* e qual equação utilizamoos")
    st.subheader("Faça o Upload do seu Arquivo de Dados abaixo:")
    upload_file = st.file_uploader("Upload Data",type=["csv","xlsx"])

    if upload_file is not None:
        df = pd.read_excel(upload_file)
        st.dataframe(df)
    else:
        df = pd.read_csv(upload_file)
        st.dataframe(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if-else statement needs to be modified to:

```
if upload_file is not None:
    if upload_file.name[0][-4:] == 'xlsx':
        df = pd.read_excel(upload_file)
        st.dataframe(df)
    else:
        df = pd.read_csv(upload_file)
        st.dataframe(df)
```

Comment: i change but still didn't worked...why you wrote [-4:], what that means? Returned this error 'UploadedFile object is not subscriptable'.

Comment: In order to determine whether the file is a csv file or an xlsx file.

Comment: humm i get it. But didn't worked, seems the problem now is here ´if upload_file[-4:] == xlsx:´

Comment: you can try `uploaded_file.name[0][-4:]`.

Comment: The function from streamlit to upload a file is 'upload_file'. But still didn't worked changing to `uploaded_file.name[0][-4:] `... The code which determine the extesion is this one: `upload_file = st.file_uploader("Upload Data",type=["csv","xlsx"])`

Comment: i found the solution. Needs to change `upload_file.name[-4:]` to `upload_file.name[-3:]` just change the number 4 to 3

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be taken into consideration which is utilizing `glob`, Python built-in module/function.

```
import glob
selected_df = []
all_files_csv = glob.glob("*.csv")
all_files_xlsx = glob.glob("*.xlsx")
for filename in all_files_csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    selected_df.append(df)
for filename in all_files_xlsx:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    selected_df.append(df)
```

Hope this helped!